Existence of a solution of a k-Hessian equation with Neumann conditions
I am interested in existence of solutions of PDE in the
$$\begin{cases}
    \sigma_{k+1}(D^2 u) = C & \Omega \\ 
    \langle T_{k}(D^2u),n\rangle =1 & \partial \Omega
\end{cases}$$
Where $\sigma_{k+1}$ is the $k+1$ elementary symmetric function of degree $k+1$. $T_{k}$ Newton tensor
$$[T_{k}]_{ij}(A) = \delta^{i,i_1,\cdots,i_k}_{j,j_1,\cdots,j_k}A_{i_1j_1}\cdots A_{i_kj_k}$$
Where to look and if it is not proven yet how to start?
